# How to merge rows and fill empty columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Name | Age | Gender | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joey | 18 |  |  |
| Joey |  | Male |  |
| Joey |  |  | Engineer |

I tried `groupby().first()` but that doesn't work
because it gives such a table:

| Name | Age | Gender | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joey | 18 |  |  |

But I want a table like this:

| Name | Age | Gender | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joey | 18 | Male | Engineer |

I have table like this, and I want to merge all the rows by name and get age, gender and occupation in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `''` with NaN, `groupby` "Name", then use `first`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('Name').first().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Name   Age Gender Occupation
0  Joey  18.0   Male   Engineer
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt give this output, it rather gives output of the first row

Comment: @RiddhiDua I updated, see if it works now

Comment: Works perfect, Thankyou.